# in GObject of glib I confuse that whether the instance object of subclass that derive from parent class inherit properties of parent class or not?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, glib, gobject

***first issue:***
in GObject I confuse that whether the instance object of subclass deriving from parent class inherits properties of parent class or not?
***second issue:***
in GObject g_object_class_install_properties function adds properties into itself class in class initializer function,but in effect these properties for each instance object of class have a copy.in other words, each instance object of class have a copy of these properties.

in addition, I read GObject code snippet.
at below code in Gobject.c file：

```
class->set_property = g_object_do_set_property;
class->get_property = g_object_do_get_property;
```

***firstly*** when are above functions called?
***secondly*** if subclass derive from parent class subclass overrides these motheds (set_property and get_property),then if g_object_new creats new subclass instance and set properties value the set_property callback function is only called ,  whether after calling subclass set_property it calls set_property method of parent class or not ?
I don't know that after only calling at a time set_property of subclass,Is set_property method of parent class called at a time?

if you know these issues,please spend you time for anwsering my isses, thank you in advance very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not yet seen the ***[GNOME Developer](https://developer.gnome.org/)*** site, it has several pages of useful information relevant to the questions you ask.  The links pointed to below contain very simple example code, followed by very detailed descriptions of what happens in the code.  The example pages I have cited (and linked) below address your questions specifically, but much more content on the topic is available in surrounding pages.

First issue:

> Derivable types can be subclassed further, and their class and
>   instance structures form part of the public API which must not be
>   changed if API stability is cared about. They are declared using
>   G_DECLARE_DERIVABLE_TYPE:

See examples here: 
***[G_DECLARE_DERIVABLE_TYPE()](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/howto-gobject.html)***

Second issue:

> generic get/set mechanism for object properties. When an object is
>   instantiated, the object's class_init handler should be used to
>   register the object's properties with
>   g_object_class_install_properties.

See examples here: ***[Object properties](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-properties.html)***

I believe your specific question:
*when are above functions called?*
is addressed is great detail in these, and surrounding paragraphs in the *Object Properties* link above:

> If the user's GValue had been set to a valid value,
>   ***[g_object_set_property](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-set-property)*** would have proceeded with calling the object's
>   set_property class method. Here, since our implementation of Foo did
>   override this method, execution would jump to foo_set_property after
>   having retrieved from the GParamSpec the param_id [4] which had been
>   stored by ***[g_object_class_install_property](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-class-install-property)***.
>
> Once the property has been set by the object's set_property class
>   method, execution returns to ***[g_object_set_property](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-set-property)*** which makes sure
>   that the "notify" signal is emitted on the object's instance with the
>   changed property as parameter unless notifications were frozen by
>   ***[g_object_freeze_notify](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-freeze-notify)***.